# Second monitor for 2009 Mac Pro

Tags: display, mac-pro

I have a [2009 Mac Pro](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-eight-core-2.26-early-2009-nehalem-specs.html) with a ATI Radeon HD 4870 (option).

It is connected to a [2009 24" Cinema Display](http://www.everymac.com/monitors/apple/studio_cinema/specs/apple-led-cinema-display-24-inch-specs.html).

If I want to add a second monitor (non-Apple), what type of monitor/connector/cable do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the second monitor you want to add ?
By reading configuration of your Mac Pro I find this (in the graphic card section) :

> It has both a Mini DisplayPort and a dual-link DVI port.

So I think you can connect two display devices on your Mac :

- Your Cinema Display on the mini display port
- Your other display on the DVI port

According to your second monitor, you can connect it directly on the DVI port or you should use a adapter (for example a VGA-to-DVI adpater).

Hope this helps !

Comment: I understand my Cinema Display is a Mini-Displayport device, which means I would have to get a DVI display as second monitor, right?

Comment: You can get any display that you want, you should juste make sure that the right adapter exist. In my post I take a VGA connector for example but it can be something else if the adapter to DVI exist on the market. But if you don't want to use an adapter, you can do as you say and buy a monitor with DVI connector.

Comment: And my graphics card and Mac OS X will recognise the monitor as a second monitor just like that?

Comment: I suppose, the best way to know is to ask a friend with a DVI display and try to plug his/her monitor on your Mac and see what happens but I see no reason why it shouldn't be working.